# navigator geolocation timeout in background

Tags: android, cordova, background, geolocation, timeout

i am using the navigator.geolocation in the browser to tracking the position to a Database.

When I go to another browser tab, the operation catch in the onError event with Timeout error.
Also in Android with Apache Cordova with the official geolocation plugin, has the same behavior. When I lock the screen, the app steel working in background, but the geolocations gets timeout. I now that steel working in background becouse my database store the error.message.

I dont want to use https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt becouse is not open source and so expensive.

Do you now if there are a fix to solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Try this plugin: https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: Thanks! I would try it

Answer (score 0):

in your config.xml put this

```
<feature name="Geolocation">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.GeoBroker" />
</feature>
```

Source

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

also check this out

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/geolocation/geolocation.html

this plugin can help you keep alive the process.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode